# Can't change default shortcut behaviour in gnome

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 16.10, workspaces, ubuntu-gnome

I want to use Super+Up and Super+Down to switch workspaces on gnome 3.20. After defining the shortcuts in the keyboard settings, Super+Up and Super+Down still do their original behavior: maximize/unmaximize.

How can I get them to work?
[*See shortcuts from the keyboard settings*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELFWu.png)

Comment: Why don't you want to use the standard shortcut ctrl+alt+up/down/left/right ?

Comment: These are slower to use compared to Super Up/Down, and I change workspaces a lot. I use those for tiling as I do that less often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings panel is buggy: setting a *default* shortcut to a new behaviour **won't change the shortcut. It will still perform the old behaviour**.

To correct this:

1. Open the `dconf editor` by typing dconf in the Activities search
   bar.
2. Go to `org>gnome>desktop>wm>keybindings`
3. Find the old behaviour
4. Uncheck *Use default value* and remove the shortcut you want to use from the *Custom Value* field. (Syntax is `['<Modifier>Key1', '<Modifier>Key2']`
5. Define your shortcut on the new behaviour.

For example: I removed `'<Super>Up'` from the `maximize` behaviour and defined `['<Super>Up']` as the custom value for the `switch-to-workspace-up` behaviour.